# Check two columns are both TRUE, if they are, populate third column with data

Tags: excel, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two columns that can be either true or false. If column `1` is TRUE and column `2` is `FALSE` I want column `3` to show `"A"`. If both columns `1` & `2` are `TRUE`, i want column `3` to show `"B"`. If both columns are `FALSE`, i want column `3` to show `FALSE`. Here is what i tried.

```
=IF(P3=TRUE,"A", IF(AND(P3=TRUE, Q3=TRUE),"B", "C"))
```

If it helps, Column `1` will never be false if Column `2` is `TRUE`.

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16tzwcQ32E8Not-8Qgg-fc1kAtym-taJ5IctTI9HdkfY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ifs-function-36329a26-37b2-467c-972b-4a39bd951d45) is ideal for this.

```
IFS(B1, "B", A1, "A", TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: I assumed the omission of the `TRUE` was an oversight so added as an edit.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the following:

- If both are TRUE, return "B"
- ElseIf A is TRUE, return "A"
- Else return FALSE.

```
=IF(AND(A1,B1),"B",IF(A1,"A",FALSE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One more option with `CHOOSE`:

```
=CHOOSE(A2+B2+1,FALSE,"A","B")
```

[image]